# Long Path in .net

Tags: .net, path, long-integer

I have problem in

When I want to access Directory Security and my path length is more then 260 char 
so I got solution from this link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton.aspx

But when I try to access the GetAccessControl() of the directory it's give error no implementation so I want to implement unmanaged code for GetAccessControl() or any other solution you have

```
[DllImport("mscorlib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
static extern int GetAccessControl(string lpPathName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

public static int GetAccess(string dirPath)
{
    return GetAccessControl(@"\\?\" + dirPath, IntPtr.Zero);

}
```

Derive from this class System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity

Comment: Mscorlib.dll is a *managed* assembly, it doesn't export any functions that you can pinvoke.  It is unclear what you are trying to do, but your approach is a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this library, it was more then perfect for me to work with long path

[Link Here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-17cc7893)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Peter's library [in here](https://github.com/peteraritchie/LongPath). This will help you with the `System.IO.PathTooLongException`

LongPaths allows your code to support long paths by providing a replacement for the following `System.IO` types: `FileInfo`, `DirectoryInfo`, `FileSystemInfo`, `FileInfo`, `DirectoryInfo`, `FileSystemInfo`

Like you can replace the `System.IO` types with the below aliases

```
using Path = Pri.LongPath.Path;
using Directory = Pri.LongPath.Directory;
using DirectoryInfo = Pri.LongPath.DirectoryInfo;
using File = Pri.LongPath.File;
using FileSystemInfo = Pri.LongPath.FileSystemInfo;
```

I hope this helps.